# Concatenating Rows in For Each/IF Statment

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate rows.

The first cell is populated correctly; however, each cell after that is the same as the first cell.

- The first cell is `FS_Tier_1 , FS_CAP_1_001`
- The next cell should be `FS_Tier_1 , FS_CAP_1_002`
- The cell after that should be `FS_Tier_1 , FS_CAP_1_003`, and so on.

Each cell shows `FS_Tier_1 , FS_CAP_1_001`.

```
Sub Concatenate_Cap1()

  With Worksheets("PD Code Structure")
      Dim i As Integer
      Dim cell As Range
      Dim Rng1 As Range
      Set Rng1 = Range("F2:F1006")
      i = 2

      For Each cell In Rng1

          If InStr(Cells(i, 3).Value, "FS_Tier_") And InStr(Cells(i, 8).Value, "FS_CAP_1_") Then
              Range("F2:F1006").Formula = Cells(i, 3).Value & " , " & Cells(i, 8).Value
              i = i + 1
          End If

      Next cell
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the whole range to the same value here.

```
Range("F2:F1006").Formula = Cells(i, 3).Value & " , " & Cells(i, 8).Value
```

Something like this should work:

```
Sub Concatenate_Cap1()

    Dim c As Range, rw As range, v3, v8

    For Each c in Worksheets("PD Code Structure").Range("F2:F1006")
        v3 = c.EntireRow.cells(3).value
        v8 = c.EntireRow.cells(8).value
        If InStr(v3, "FS_Tier_") And InStr(v8, "FS_CAP_1_") Then
            c.value = v3 & " , " & v8
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```