# Concatenating Using Case Statement with Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate Tier Code and Cap Code where Cap Level = 2.  I was able to successfully do the concatenation earlier using a case statement, without the condition that Cap Level = 2.  However, now that I'm trying to add that condition, I keep getting the error "Type Mistmatch".   I've tried setting Range("E3:E24").Value = 2 and = "2".  Both ways, I still get the error.

My data currently looks like this:

[image]

I've been playing around with this for at least an hour now and reading other questions about case statements with multiple conditions/criteria, but I haven't been able to get my code to work properly.

```
Sub Concat_ParentCode_Cap1_001()

With Worksheets("PD Code Structure")

Dim ParentCode As Range
Dim TierCode As String
Dim CapCode As String

CapCode = "FS_CAP_1_001"
TierCode = "FS_Tier_1"
Set ParentCode = Range("F3:F24")

        Select Case True
            Case CapCode = "FS_CAP_1_001" And Range("E3:E24").Value = "2"
                ParentCode = TierCode & "." & CapCode
        End Select

End With
End Sub
```

I would like my data to look like this:

[image]

Comment: what's wrong with the code that you accepted as an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694095/code-not-concatenating-rows-in-for-each-if-statment

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things in the code provided that will cause it not too work, but the main thing is a loop to check each cell.

Give this a shot:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Concat_ParentCode_Cap1_001()

    Dim tierCode As String
    tierCode = "FS_TIER_1."

    With Worksheets("PD Code Structure")

        Dim capCode As Range

        For Each capCode In .Range("F2:F24")

            If Len(capCode.Offset(, -1)) Then

                Dim capParent As String
                capParent = capCode.Value

            End If

            If capCode.Offset(, -2).Value = 2 Then
                capCode.Offset(, -1).Value = tierCode & capParent
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code, but it didn't concatenate the desired values.  I ran it without any errors, but nothing showed in the Cap Parent column.

Comment: @HeatherD - I may small adjustments and confirmed in my file. try now

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use VBA for this ? This looks like something you can do with just an if statement on excel. =if(B2=2,CONCAT(A1,".",D1),""). This is of course assuming the columns are listed A-D above.

Comment: I have a ton of cells to do this for at multiple levels, so I'd rather use VBA than doing an If statement in Excel.  I'm just trying to do this as efficiently and quickly as possible.